# Can men pray at home for avoiding the bad smell of people at mosque?

Tags: salat, taharah, masjid, perfume

Can men pray at home for avoiding the bad smell of people at mosque?
Its very irritating. can i pray at home for concentrate on salah by avoiding those bad smells coming from people's sweating dress or uncleaned dress.
or any other techniques to be concentrated in salah avoiding the bad smell.

Answer (score 1):

What makes you guarantee yourself to not be one of those men you criticize? Allah Almighty said in [Surah Al-Hujurat (49) — Verse 11](https://quran.com/49/11):

In Arabic (the exact wording):

> ...يَا أَيُّهَا الَّذِينَ آمَنُوا لَا يَسْخَرْ قَوْمٌ مِنْ قَوْمٍ عَسَى أَنْ يَكُونُوا خَيْرًا مِنْهُمْ

In English (in what it means):

> O you who have believed, let not a people ridicule [another] people; perhaps they may be better than them.

The verse is also forbidding people from (besides **mocking**) **despising** and **belittling** one another.

It is summer and such smells are common to exist, so maybe you can voluntarily buy an air conditioner for the mosque, so it would get rid of the smell in addition to the many other benefits you and the worshipers would gain.

---

For more explanation about the verse, [see here](https://www.alukah.net/sharia/0/95574/)